# respond_with and how to set redirect location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following that update user profile. It does perfectly fine with base url (http://domain_name.com/users/).

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_with @user do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      if current_user.becomes(User) == @user
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      end
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to @user }         
      format.json { render :status => :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => 'edit' }
      format.json { render :status => :bad_request }
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to move it into admin namespace (http://domain_name.com/admin/users/). And what I try is to change

```
redirect_to @user
```

to

```
redirect_to admin_user_path(@user)
```

then I got:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  #respond_with(@user) do |format|
  respond_with(@user, :location => admin_user_path(@user)) do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      if current_user.becomes(User) == @user
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      end
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to admin_user_path(@user) }
      format.json { render :status => :ok }
    else          
      format.html { render :action => 'edit', :location => edit_admin_path(user) } 
      format.json { render :status => :bad_request }
    end
  end
end
```

But it does not work. I also try to change

```
respond_with(@user) do |format|
```

to something like

```
respond_with(@user, :location => admin_user_path(@user)) do |format|
```

But it doesn't work too. Can anyone have some experience, please give me some advice or explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the following line:

```
  respond_with(@user, :location => admin_user_path(@user)) do |format|
```

Seems a bit odd to me. I would've thought this should be `respond_with(@user) do |format|`

Also take a read of the following: [Ryan's Scraps - Cleaner RESTful Controllers / respond_with](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with). Ryan states the following under **Pre-Action Overriding**:

> It’s also possible to override standard resource handling by passing in a block to respond_with specifying which formats to override for that action.

From this you will see that the formats that are to be overrided are declared at the top of the class using `respond_to`